# postsave stop database update

Tags: database

User is adding a new email. Call to civicrm_pre detects a problem that requires that the update not happen. It hasn't actually happened by the time civicrm_post or post_save_civicrm_email is called. The update actually happens after post_save is called.

How do I abort the update?

Answer (score 2):

While I suppose you could empty the `$params` array, it would be a bit clumsy.  Meanwhile you'll need a way to notify the user in context, so something form-specific would be helpful.

Instead of using hook_civicrm_pre, you might consider using [hook_civicrm_validateForm()](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_validateForm).  You'd be able to run the same checks, but in case the value is no good, you could send the user back to fix it.

Comment: I tried adding hook_civicrm_validateFom, but it never gets called. Is there something I must do to make sure it does get called?

Comment: Not sure where the problem is happening, but it should be getting called on any form you use.  Try setting an error on a field you know is there by doing something like `$errors['first_name'] = 'DEBUG TEST';`